# How do I create and name checkboxes within a foreach loop PHP

Tags: php

I seem to be a little stuck with this.

I am trying to create checkboxes within a table of data within a foreach loop.

```
    foreach($datas as $data){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='counter[]'></input></td>";
      echo "<td>" .$data['employeeName']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$data['amount']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$data['reason']. "</td>";
    }
```

This will print out a table of employee reimbursements that have yet to be reimbursed. From here I am wanting to be able to have the user check the checkboxes in multiple rows, and run a SQL database UPDATE statement to update the date of reimbursement in the database.

I'm really confused on how I would name the checkboxes, and submit them to the following page. Thank you in advance for your help, and please let me know if you need any additional information!

Comment: Yep, totally meant update, sorry been a long night and half asleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to give the employee id as the value of the checkbox

```
<form name="employee" method="POST">
        foreach($datas as $data)
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='counter[]' value=$data['id']></input></td>";
          echo "<td>" .$data['employeeName']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" .$data['amount']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" .$data['reason']. "</td>";
        }
<button type="submit"  value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When You Submit the form you will get all employees id checked in the form.

```
$emloyee=$_POST['counter'];
```

You will get the data as array.

Then for each employeeid you can update the date of reimbursement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was everything I needed to keep going! You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass value of employee id in checkbox; so when you select checkbox and submit form, you will get all checked employee id's in post data. Here is complete code that may be useful for you to go through.

```
// On form post this code will be executed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // this will give you all employee id which you have selected in array
    // it will be blank if you have not selected any employee
    $counter = isset($_POST['counter']) && !empty($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : [];

    // update statement here 
    if (!empty($counter)) {
        foreach ($counter as $key => $empId) {
            // update statement goes here
            // you can update statement based on $empId here
        }
    }   
}

// sample data; make sure you have employee id that you can use in update statement later on
$datas = [
    ['id' => 1, 'employeeName' => 'John', 'amount' => 100, 'reason' => 'reason 1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'employeeName' => 'Heily', 'amount' => 200, 'reason' => 'reason 2'],
    ['id' => 3, 'employeeName' => 'Keith', 'amount' => 150, 'reason' => 'reason 3']
];

// Your form
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<table>";
foreach($datas as $data){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='counter[]' value='".$data['id']."'></input></td>"; // added employee id as value here 
    echo "<td>" .$data['employeeName']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$data['amount']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$data['reason']. "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "<form>";
```